# Does AWS use distributed systems?

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, distributed-system

Does AWS use Distributed Systems when it manages the ec2 instances that are in different zones to communicate together?

If not, how do they manage such communications?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, AWS EC2 instances in different availability zones communicate over a distributed system. The underlying infrastructure utilizes networking technologies, such as **Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)** and the **AWS backbone network**, to enable seamless and reliable communication between instances across different zones. The details of this networking architecture are managed by AWS, providing a distributed and resilient environment for EC2 instances.